# Replace rows in a dataframe by matching individual rows of another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I've two dataframes and I want to replace some rows of the first dataframe by inserting rows of the second dataframe. 
The following is what I did until now, but this is not the result that I want to have.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(0, 0,0,0 ,1, 1, 1, 2, 2), b = rep(0, 9)) 
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1), b = rep(1, 2)) 
df1[match(df2$a, df1$a), ] <- df2
> df1
  a b
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 1 1
6 1 0
7 1 0
8 2 0
9 2 0
```

What I really want to have is a dataframe which also adopts the second row of df2 and looks like the following:

```
> df1
  a b
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 1 1
6 1 1
7 1 0
8 2 0
9 2 0
```

Is there a function which does this kind of matching?

Comment: I think there's a problem with your df2... right now it's a dataframe where everything is a 1.

Comment: I don't see any unique values in neither `df2$a` or `df1$a` so I have no idea why do you expect R to decide that they are unique

Comment: I expect R to do the replacement in the following way. 

First match between df1$a and df2$a so replace the first row where match was found. 
Now jump to the next row of df2 and look for the NEXT match(not the same match as before). And so forth.... I'm not pretty sure how this can be done. That's why I have asked for any suggestions.

Comment: Ok thanks, but downvoting does not fix my problem. I think the problem is clear and I've tried to give a reproducible example of what I've tried and what I want to have. 
The real problem is much more complex and contains much more rows and columns but the problem is that there is no other characteristic which I could use to refine  the join/merge/match commands

Comment: I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: Either-way, this is the best I could come up with `library(data.table) ; setDT(df1)[, indx := 1:.N, by = rleid(a)] ; setDT(df2)[, indx := 1:.N, by = rleid(a)] ; df1[df2, b := i.b, on = c(indx = "indx", a = "a")]`

Comment: Hey David, 

I've never used data.table. How could one do the replacement for several columns and not only column b. Imagine df1 and df2 have several columns called c,d,e ... and so forth . How would one then change the "j - part" (specified columns) in a data table?

Comment: Can you show an example? Also, I'm not seeing your messages without a @

Answer (score 1):

The point is you have rows(5,6,7) with identical values:

```
> which(df1$a %in% df2$a)
[1] 5 6 7

> df1[which(df1$a %in% df2$a),]
  a b
5 1 0
6 1 0
7 1 0
```

So if you join or replace, one condition is not enough to replace rows 5,6 and exclude 7 as in your desired result.

if you want to replace n rows, where n=the number of rows in df2, you can use the following. It will replace the first two rows with a=1.

```
df1[which(df1$a %in% df2$a)[1:nrow(df2)],] <- df2

> df1
  a b
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 1 1
6 1 1
7 1 0
8 2 0
9 2 0
```

Comment: I see this point. Is there a way to overcome this problem? Maybe a condition that counts how often this should be done or something like this.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Do you want to change the 5th and 6th rows only?, i.e. certain rows by index?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Do you want to change the 5th and 6th rows only?, i.e. certain rows by index?

Comment: No not by index, but by several of these matches described above.  And these matches differ in length. In the example above, there should be two replacements, since df2$a has two values with 1.  

Imagine that the df1 and df2 also have values in df$a like 5,6, and so on. There the replacements could be 3 and 4 and so forth.

Comment: For this specific case, you can use:
 `df1[which(df1$a %in% df2$a)[1:nrow(df2)],] <- df2`